# How to call method on code behind class from webpart ascx

Tags: web-part

I have a very simple webpart with the code behind below.

```
 using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.SharePoint;

    namespace PeopleWebPart.PeopleWebPart {
        [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
        public partial class PeopleWebPart : WebPart {
            public PeopleWebPart() {}

            protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
                base.OnInit(e);
                InitializeControl();
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                 //repeater.DataSource and binding all good to go
            }

            public String testMtd(String title){
               return "foo "+Title;
            }
    }
```

I also have the following ascx file.

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# Eval("Title") %>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

The Eval is working and all is good but I want to also be able to call the testMtd method from the ascs file.

Is this possible ?

**UPDATE**

For completeness on this:
I solved it by making testMtd a static because it was just processing the string. The accepted answer below is the way to go if it can't be it a static.

```
        public static String testMtd(String title){
           return "foo "+title;
        }
```

Then it's easy to call it like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
      <%# PeopleWebPart.testMtd("<%# Eval("Title") %>") %>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass your webpart class as property to ascx codebehind class

```
 public partial class YOUR_ASCX_CLASS: UserControl
 {

     public YOUR_WEBPART_CLASS Webpart { get; set; }

 }
```

then you can call webpart class method in your ascx codebehind

```
Webpart.testMtd()
```

If testMd() method is just for processing data you can put it on another class (some Utility class) as static method and call it directly.

Comment: Figured out the static method call last night, by just trying around. Thanks for the first option, didn't know you can pass a class as a property to the ascx. Docs on web-parts are so bad, or I'm not finding the right docs.